# How to recursively implement a deep flatten on Iterable?

Tags: kotlin, generics, recursion, flatten, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Having seen [`flatten`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flatten.html), I was looking for something that would be a `deepFlatten`, i.e., it would work with not only `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` (it's pretty much the same for `Array`s, but let's focus on `Iterable` now for brevity), but also with `Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<T>>>`, `Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<Iterable<T>>>>` and so on...

Of course, the result would have to be `List<T>`, which the standard `flatten()` doesn't provide - it would return `List<Iterable<T>` (or a `List` with more nested `Iterable`s).

I was trying to work with `reified` generics:

```
inline fun <reified E, T> Iterable<E>.deepFlatten(): List<T> = when(E::class) {
    Iterable<*>::class -> (this as Iterable<Iterable<*>>).flatten().deepFlatten()
    else -> flatten()
}
```

But this obviously is flooded with errors:

- `T` seems pretty undeducible
- You cannot have a `::class` of an *interface*
- You cannot recurse on an `inline` function

Are there any workarounds on the above problems? Or, even better, is there a cleaner approach to the problem?

---

To demonstrate an example for completeness, I'd like to be able to do:

```
fun main() {
    val data: List<List<List<Int>>> = listOf(
            listOf(listOf(1, 2, 3), listOf(5, 6), listOf(7)),
            listOf(listOf(8, 9), listOf(10, 11, 12, 13))
    )

    print(data.deepFlatten()) // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
}
```

The depth of nested `Iterable`s (they need not be the same type - it's important that they are generically `Iterable`) can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun <T> Iterable<*>.deepFlatten(): List<T> {
    val result = ArrayList<T>()
    for (element in this) {
        when (element) {
            is Iterable<*> -> result.addAll(element.deepFlatten())
            else -> result.add(element as T)
        }
    }
    return result
}
...

println(data.deepFlatten<Int>())
```

You have to specify the type explicitly and you lose compile-time safety. But it can flatten lists of any nesting and with elements of different types (`[1, "foo", [3, "bar"]]` -> `[ 1, "foo", 3, "bar"]`)

I would prefer a different solution. Something like this:

```
typealias It2<T> = Iterable<Iterable<T>>
typealias It3<T> = Iterable<It2<T>>
typealias It4<T> = Iterable<It3<T>>
typealias It5<T> = Iterable<It4<T>>
//etc...

fun <T> It3<T>.flatten2(): List<T> = flatten().flatten()
fun <T> It4<T>.flatten3(): List<T> = flatten2().flatten()
fun <T> It5<T>.flatten4(): List<T> = flatten3().flatten()
//etc...

...
println(data.flatten2())
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you might achieve the very same behavior using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream):

**Using `Collection<?>`**:

```
public static Stream<?> deepFlatMap(Object o) {
   if (o instanceof Collection<?>) {
       return ((Collection<?>) o).stream().flatMap(i -> deepFlatMap(i));
   }
   return Stream.of(o);
}
```

**Using `Iterable<?>`**:

```
public static Stream<?> deepFlatMap(Object o) {
   if (o instanceof Iterable<?>) {
       Spliterator<?> spliterator = ((Iterable<?>) o).spliterator();
       return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false).flatMap(i -> deepFlatMap(i));
   }
   return Stream.of(o);
}
```

The usage is pretty straightforward: `deepFlatMap(list).forEach(System.out::println);`

As long as I don't know Kotlin, I hope this can at least help you with rewriting the idea.

---

**Edit:** As long as you want to specify the return target generic type, you should use another wrapper method (don't forget to change the name in the recursive method):

```
public static <T> Stream<T> deepFlatMap(Collection<?> collection) {
    return (Stream<T>) internalDeepFlatMap(collection);
}

public static Stream<?> internalDeepFlatMap(Object o) {
   if (o instanceof Collection<?>) {
       return ((Collection<?>) o).stream().flatMap(i -> internalDeepFlatMap(i));
   }
   return Stream.of(o);
}
```

Usage with specifying the generic type explicitly:

```
MyClass.<Integer>deepFlatMap(list).map(i -> i + 1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Any chance I could retain the innermost type in the return type? In my case, `Int`? Throwing `Object` everywhere seems a little off, when we have generics.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a decent workaround, although I will keep trying to adapt it to `Sequence` from Kotlin rather than a plain Java's `Stream`.